# jQuery.post not firing on a form submit

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="/static/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search-form").submit(function() {
            var formInput = $("#search-box").val();
            $.post("/userq/", {"formInput": formInput});
            return true;
         });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="/search/" id="search-form">
        <input type="text" name="formInput" class="searchbox" id="search-box">
        <input type="submit" VALUE="Search" class="submitbutton" id="submit-button">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my html page. When the form (#search-form) is submitted I first want the post to the url "/userq" and then the final action of "/search" to be submitted. But the $.post to "/userq" never happens. If I use the javascript debugger and breakpoint at $.post then the post fires. What is wrong here?

Comment: have you verified server side that the post is not happening?

Comment: Why not change the form method to post and the action to the location you want it to be?  I don't see you doing anything with the result of the post...

Comment: @Maess And this is type of people which I don't like. He ask and gone... We trying help people but they don't give us any feedback.

Comment: @RuneFS Yes. Verified it on the server side. It is not working.

Comment: what's the error in the developer console in the browser then?

Comment: I don't see any error. With the javascript debugger, the post actually happens? Some timing related issue?

Comment: @Maess using the separate post for making sure that the request is coming from a real browser and not a bot.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sended = false;
        $("#search-form").on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formInput = $("#search-box").val();
            $.post("/userq/", {"formInput": formInput})
            .done(function(){
                if(!sended)
                    $("#search-form").submit();
                sended = true;
            });
         });
    })
```

Comment: But I want the normal action to be followed as well i.e., submitting to "/search" url.

Comment: So you want post it twice? First time on `/search/` and second ond `/userq/` ?

Comment: Yes. But slightly different .. .first post to "/userq" and then get to "/search". I think it is a timing issue.

Comment: That is causing an infinite loop of post to "/userq".

Comment: That is also not working. There is no request to "/search". I think preventDefault() is stopping that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be, as you have defined '**GET**' method and '**ACTION**' in form element
Try to put  `event.preventDefault();` to stop form from submitting normally so that it can call `jQuery.post()`.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search-form").submit(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formInput = $("#search-box").val();
            $.post("/userq/", {"formInput": formInput});
            return true;
         });
    });
```

Try this and then check.

Comment: Ok .. going to try this and will let you know.

Comment: But this stops the normal action. How can I make sure that the "/search" is also subsequently submitted?

Comment: if you want to perform both action subsequently, then you can trigger form submit and jQuery.post() event on button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Actually realized that it is not possible to do. The jquery post actually never happens because the form submit replaces the page.